# How to verify that a tentative state-space representation of an ARMA(1,1) process is valid

Tags: arima, state-space-models

Brockwell & Davis example 9.1.2. show the state-space representation for {$Y_t$}, an ARMA(1,1) process. They claim that the 2 equations below are the **observation equation** and **state equation** respectively for {$Y_t$}:

(1) ${Y}_t=[\theta $    $  1] \begin{bmatrix} X_{t-1}\\X_t\end{bmatrix}$

(2) $\begin{bmatrix} X_{t}\\X_{t+1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\0 & \phi  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} X_{t-1}\\X_t\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\Z_{t+1}\end{bmatrix}$

with $\mathbf X_1=\begin{bmatrix} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\phi^jZ_{-j} \\\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\phi^jZ_{1-j}\end{bmatrix}$ and $Z_t$~$WN(0,\sigma^2)$

I have 2 questions here:

1. How can I convince myself that the above is a valid state-space representation for the ARMA(1,1) process?
2. How do I think about what the unobserved state vector **$\mathbf X_t$**=$\begin{bmatrix} X_{t-1}\\X_{t}\end{bmatrix}$ represents in this case?

Comment: Hint. For 1., use $Y_t = \theta X_{t-1} + X_t$, and apply $(1 - \phi B)$ to each side.

Comment: Note that the boldface notation $\mathbf{X}_t$ for the state vector in the book. It  should be used for $\mathbf{X}_1$. The same is true for your question 2.

Comment: That was a very good hint; it did it for me; I was able to show that this is indeed the space-state representation. Very neat. Thank you.

Comment: @Yves: why don't you put your hint as an answer (since it is the key point) and add an answer to part 2?

Comment: I agree about the boldface point; I just wasn't able to make it boldface in markdown

Comment: The only truck here is to bring the lagged variable into the same vector as contemporaneous

Comment: You can use `$\mathbf{X}_t$` to get $\mathbf{X}_t$.

Comment: I added the boldface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that $|\phi| < 1$ we can as in the OP define $X_t
:= \sum_{j = 0}^\infty \phi^j Z_{t -j}$, so $(1-\phi B) \,X_t =
Z_t$. Let us denote temporarily by $Y^\star_t$ the observation of the
candidate State-Space (SS) representation. Since $Y_t^{\star} := \theta
X_{t-1} + X_{t}$, by applying $(1 - \phi B)$ to each side of the last
relation, we get the relation (1) with $Y^\star_t$ replacing
$Y_t$. So, the same model holds for $Y^\star_t$ and $Y_t$. And the SS
representation with $\mathbf{X}_t := [X_{t-1}, \, X_t]'$ gives the
wanted model for $Y_t$.

The series $X_t$ applies a linear filter $1/(1 - \phi B)$ to the white
noise $Z_t$. We can describe $X_t$ as a "coloured noise", yet I can
not see a better interpretation to answer to question 2.  To get an
interpretable (equivalent) representation, we could go with the state
vector $\mathbf{V}_t = [Y_{t},\, \hat{Y}_{t+1|t}]'$ and the
observation equation $Y_t = [1,\, 0] \mathbf{V}_t$. This generalises
to the $\text{ARMA}(p, \,q)$ case with $r := \max\{p,\,q +1\}$ by
taking $\mathbf{V}_t := [Y_{t},\, \hat{Y}_{t+1|t},
\,\dots,\,Y_{t+r-1|t}]'$ with the obvious observation equation $Y_t =
[1,\, 0, \, \dots,\,0]'\mathbf{V}_t$. This is sometimes called the
*Akaike SS representation*.

Note also that in a SS representation, we need an initial covariance
matrix, be it that $\mathbf{X}_0$ or that of $\mathbf{X}_1$, in both
cases conditional on the empty observation set preceding the
observation of $Y_1$. For the SS representation of the
$\text{ARMA}(1,\,1)$ above, this covariance matrix is easily derived.

Comment: This is terrific. Thank you again for all these insights. I can tell you are quite an expert in this field.

Comment: Question 2 was sort of trick question as it is very difficult to conceptualize the states; but I like your "colored noise" description. This is a clue that spectral analysis of $X_t$ might give us some additional insights into its DGP.